# why the response status of (ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer) solrserver.add(docs) is 0 when the solr server is disconnect?

Tags: solr, solrj

when i use the add() method of ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer to add documents to a solr server  which is disconnect,i found the status of response is 0 (i think status is not 0);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your context is not really clear, be aware that the ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer is adding documents in a asynch + buffered way (by means of an internal blocking queue and several dequeueing threads) so that could be the reason why you miss something in case of a server disconnection....but it's a shot in the dark